# Implementing inertia-links in storybook

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, storybook, inertiajs

Hi im trying out storybook, loving it so far!

My issue is that im implementing it in my Laravel app, with inertia. Im trying to render a navigation link component, which uses the inertia links wrapper: https://inertiajs.com/links

The component is registered in storybook, but does not render, because the of the inertia-link replacing the html in the code. Is there a way to import the inertia link in storybook, making rendering possible?

If I manually change the tag in the html via inspection to an anchor tag (), the component renders. Which tells me that it is, indeed the inertia-link, giving me a headache.

I have tried for some time now, I also tried searching for som time, but I simply can't find an answer :(

Will keep you updated if I make new discoveries.

**Edit**
I discovered that the console displays this error, which further makes my assumption that its the inertia-link component:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Link
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <AppNavLink href="/" >
```

**The code of the vue component:**

```
  <Link
    class="font-medium uppercase hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-400"
    :class="{
      ' text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-500': active,
    }"
  >
    <slot />
  </Link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    active: Boolean,
  },
}
</script>
```

**The story:**

```
import NavLink from '../resources/js/components/ui/AppNavLink.vue'
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

// This default export determines where your story goes in the story list
export default {
  /*  The title prop is optional.
   * See https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/configure/overview#configure-story-loading
   * to learn how to generate automatic titles
   */
  title: 'Design System/Navbar link',
  component: NavLink,
  subcomponents: { Link },
}

// We create a “template” of how args map to rendering
const Template = (args) => ({
  components: { NavLink, Link },
  setup() {
    // The args will now be passed down to the template
    return { args }
  },
  template: ' <NavLink href=args.href > Posts </NavLink>',
})

export const Default = Template.bind({})

Default.args = {
  /*  The args you need here will depend on your component */
  href: '/',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have a bad declaration on export default, it should be:

```
export default{components: {NavLink, Link}}
```

Comment: I tried this, the component still doesn't render...